# Iterate through list of list of objects

Tags: drools, rules

I have an Object called Customer. Customer object consists of List of stock objects and stock consists of List of quotes and inside quote there is a field called status. Here is my object graph.

```
class Customer{
List<Stock> stocks;
//getter and setters
}

class Stock{
List<Quote> quotes;
//getter and setters
}

class Quote{
String status;
//getter and setters
}
```

Now I need to write a rule in drl to verify if status is "initiate" in any of the list of quote object in stocks then all other values for status of quotes in all stocks for a customer is supposed to be only "initiate".

Meaning if status is "initiate" then only initiate is valid value for all quotes for all stocks for a customer. This is only for "initiate" status.

I spent a day to write a rule but with no success. I can only pass whole Customer object to rules engine. Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

The following rule fires once if the Customer is either status "Initialize" in all Quotes for all Stocks or has no "Initialize" at all, i.e., when the Customer is "clean".

```
rule checkini
  dialect "java"
when
  $c: Customer( $ss: stocks )
  Boolean( booleanValue ) 
     from accumulate( Stock( $qs: quotes ) from $ss,
     init( int notini = 0; int isini = 0; ),
     action( for( Object q: $qs )
               if( "Initiate".equals(((Quote)q).getStatus())) isini++;
               else notini++;  ),
     result( notini == 0 || isini == 0 ) )
then
  System.out.println( "clean" );
end
```

To see whether the Customer has a mish-mash of "Initiate" and anything else, negate the result condition.

Comment: Dialect "mvel" is broken in many Drools version although much has been done to improve the situation. Use `dialect "java"` within this rule to switch back to orderly compilation. Or use a static Java method to check this property, much the way the accumulate does. Or implement a custom accumulate, as explained in the Drools documentation.